# Using device orientation with 3D transforms

Tags: css, 3d, rotation, firefox-os, device-orientation

There is this project that wants to implement a cube that has sides for east/west/up/ground/north/south which are supposed to always point in the respective geolocations. The necessary data is gathered from the deviceorientation API: http://cube.ffos.lolcathost.org/

Me and lots of other users were wondering why this app is not doing what it's supposed to do. (It's supposed to run on Firefox OS or on any Android device with Firefox.) Apart from the fact that the code seems to do a lot of unnecessary things and the coding style is a shame, I don't quite understand what he is doing there.

Then I discovered hints on how to do something similar on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Using_device_orientation_with_3D_transforms

Both approaches seem to be obviously wrong: They assume that you can simply invert the device orientation by just applying `rotateX`, `rotateY` and `rotateZ` in the right order.

But there's a clear definition of the angles (alpha, beta, gamma) that the `deviceorientation` event provides: http://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/#deviceorientation And it says that the respective rotation axes are the axes of the rotated (device) frame. So you rotate by an angle alpha around the z-axis, then you rotate by an angle beta around the (now rotated!) x-axis, then you rotate by an angle gamma around the (now twice rotated!) y-axis.

Since for CSS transforms the reference frame is always the device frame, to invert these steps you would need to manually keep rotating the axis of rotation.

```
var b = e.beta,
    g = -e.gamma,
    a = e.alpha,
    axis_y = Array(0,1,0),
    axis_x = rotate(Array(1,0,0), axis_y, g),
    axis_z = rotate(rotate(Array(0,0,1), axis_y, g), axis_x, b);
```

Thus, the CSS transforms look like this:

```
document.getElementById("cube").style.transform =
    "rotate3d(" + axis_z[0] + ", " + axis_z[1] + ", " + axis_z[2] + ", " + a + "deg) " +
    "rotate3d(" + axis_x[0] + ", " + axis_x[1] + ", " + axis_x[2] + ", " + b + "deg) " +
    "rotate3d(" + axis_y[0] + ", " + axis_y[1] + ", " + axis_y[2] + ", " + g + "deg)";
```

Note that for the CSS transform function `rotate3d` "the rotation is clockwise as one looks from the end of the axis vector toward the origin" while for the provided alpha-beta-gamma "positive rotation around an axis is clockwise when viewed along the positive direction of the axis". Taking into account that the y axis for CSS transforms is pointing to the bottom of the screen we only have to invert the gamma angle in our context.

Here is my implementation of this: http://tovotu.de/tests/compass/index.html

My question is: Is this the right/best way of implementing this or is there a way to do it without rotating the axes of rotation multiple times?

Comment: Interestingly enough instead of showing the "..your device doesn't come with an orientation sensor.." message on Chrome desktop version 47.0.2526.80 m the cube is shown and all 3 coordinates have `0` as value. How can Chrome show `0` when my screen 100% does not have an orientation sensor? Should Chrome not show `null` for these values and thus also show the "..not supported.." message? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093857/device-orientation-api-returns-different-values-for-desktop-browsers

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with the Device Orientation API myself, but it was just scratching the surface - I was getting the beta and gamma values independently and applying them to the ball's velocity to roll it on the screen in a simple game demo called Cyber Orb created using the Phaser framework and rendered on Canvas (you can find more details in the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Workflows/HTML5_Gamedev_Phaser_Device_Orientation) and [Mozilla Hacks post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/04/mobile-game-development-with-the-device-orientation-and-vibration-apis/)).

The CSS 3D transforms is not my thing actually, but in my opinion - if it works, then just go for it. It looks quite simple and do the job, so no need to overcomplicate it. If there's someone who knows better way to do it, I'd also like to see it though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I have only one phone to run my own code on. And on this phone the cube behaves strangely when I hold the phone upside down (screen facing the ground). Either the phone's sensors or the sensor drivers or my implementation is crap ... But remarkably, in "most" cases the cube behaves as it should.

Comment: The API is still in a draft stage and there are differences in implementations between the browsers, so I suppose it's just that. All I can suggest is trying to test it on a different device.

You can also try and use this lib: https://github.com/richtr/Full-Tilt to see if it helps.